# MeshLab normalmap

Tags: meshlab

In the previous(1.3.3) Meshlab version,when choosing Render->shaders->normalmap,  the normal map with the familiar blue-purple colormap would show the correct normal map:
[image]
In the current (2016.12) version,  the normal map is not shown,only the texture overlay:
[image] 
[image]
**How can I show the normal colormap in the current version?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although there is a predefined shader named "normalmap" available under `Render -> Shaders` menu, it will not render the model as you think it would ("familiar blue-purple colormap").

But you can modify those shaders to achieve what you are looking for.

1. Take a back up of the following files. You can find them in `C:\Program Files\VCG\MeshLab\shaders` or wherever you have installed meshlab

   - normalmap.vert
   - normalmap.frag
2. Edit the above files as follows. You can keep the comments.

   - normalmap.vert

     > ```
     > varying vec4 baseColor;
     > void main(void)
     > {
     >     gl_Position = ftransform();
     >     baseColor = vec4(gl_Normal, 1.0);
     > }
     > ```
   - normalmap.frag

     > ```
     > varying vec4 baseColor;
     > void main(void)
     > {
     >     gl_FragColor = baseColor;
     > }
     > ```
3. From Render menu, select `Render -> Shaders -> normalmap.gdp`

   [image]
4. There you go! But remember this is a very simple shader to show normal map. If you want lighting and other effects you have to further edit the shaders.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04: `/usr/share/meshlab/shaders/`